# Is there any way to give phone rating according to its ram and processor data ? except benchmarks

Tags: ram, processor

I am trying to cluster phones of similar specifications together ie phones that have near about same performance i have only data of processors and ram associated with each phone , is there any way i can calculate which phones will have near about same performance ?

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of RAM and the CPU's specs (no. of cores, clock rate) is about the same (+/-200MHz for clock rate) then you can assume they perform about the same.
Some manufacturers have inbuilt "Benchmark detection" that boosts up the CPU for instance to gain higher listings but practically you are unable to notice and use that.

> **Conclusion:** As long as the amount of RAM and the CPU power is about the same, they all perform the same. Currently there is no major performance boost by other architectures, CPU models etc.
>   Look out for different storage rates. A faster internal storage makes a phone perform way better in normal use.